Fails on devnet works on localnet - Access violation in stack frame 5 at address 0x200005db8 of size 8
I’m facing a problem with the error Access violation in stack frame 5 at address 0x200005db8 of size 8 when I try to invoke the Initialize instruction on devnet (creates 5 accounts). I already know that this kind of error is related to stack overflow.
Anchor during compilation does not give any warnings like:
Stack offset of 7472 exceeded max offset of 4096 by 3376 bytes, please minimize large stack variable

My setup:
Anchor 0.29.0
Solana 1.18.18

I read that Anchor might not always report such errors during compilation (with stack overflow), but this should always fail when running tests. I have checked both with the Anchor started validator (anchor test ..) and with a manually started validator (solana-test-validator), and in both cases the Initialize instruction works fine. I will also mention that in Anchor.toml and for the Solana version I have locally 1.18.18, the same as the current version on devnet.
Why might I get Access violation in stack frame 5 at address 0x200005db8 of size 8 on devnet, but everything works fine locally?

This is most likely happening due to feature: EenyoWx9UMXYKpR8mW5Jmfmy2fRjzUtM7NduYMY8bx33 not being enabled on devnet and mainnet.
Your best chance it to box the accounts that need too much stack space and fix it that way by moving them on the heap. You will probably have some warning already in your code when compiling that tell you that you will most likely surpass the stack size limit of 4kb.
Here you can read about the issue:
https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/issues/1186
You can see the feature activation schedule here: https://github.com/anza-xyz/agave/wiki/Feature-Gate-Activation-Schedule
You can test locally if that feature is the problem by deactivating it locally:
solana-test-validator -r --deactivate-feature EenyoWx9UMXYKpR8mW5Jmfmy2fRjzUtM7NduYMY8bx33


This is the issue. I ran the validator with this feature disabled, and it failed with the same error as on devnet. Thank you! I was pulling my hair out wondering what was happening.
By the way, it's a pity we can no longer see the error at the compilation stage with Anchor.
Boxing does not help, with init account are still loaded to stack for some reason. I ended up manually creating a PDA accounts with system program and writing Anchor discriminator to first 8 bytes.

If you have time, could you maybe open an issue at the anchor repository? https://github.com/coral-xyz/anchor I didnt know that the warning where gone now and boxed accounts on the stack sounds very wrong.
